# In Kotlin, what is the idiomatic way to deal conditional way to initialize complex map

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-null-safety

Recently I find myself dealing with maps of <String, List<...>> like this:

```
val bc = mutableMapOf<String, MutableSet<Int>>()
if (bc[question] == null)
  bc[question] = mutableSetOf()
bc[question]!!.add(line)
```

Isn't there a better way to do this?  I've tried

```
bc[question]?.add(x) ?: = mutableSetOf(x)
```

But that won't work.  I've looked here and on the [Kotlin null-safety](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#null-safety) page
and other similar questions here but didn't find anything.  I'm still some-what new to Kotlin.

Comment: Why do you even need the `if (bc[question] == null)`?

Comment: Did you, for any reason, miss an `else` in your first snippet? Looking at your second snippet makes me think so.

Comment: @vym, no -- no else needed.  The if initializes the map entry with a set object if necessary, The second part is always executed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do it using run function to assign `mutableSetOf` you can try it

```
 bc[question]?.add(line) ?: run { bc[question] = mutableSetOf(line) }
```

Comment: [getOrPut](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/get-or-put.html) would be way more idiomatic IMO: `bc.getOrPut(question) { mutableSetOf() }.add(line)`